# Which would be better performance/loading time wise? (Java strings)

Tags: java, string, performance, loading

I'm loading assets for a game I'm making in Java. A few example lines from my code are:

```
manager.load("game/block.png", Texture.class, param);
manager.load("game/player.png", Texture.class, param);
manager.load("game/point.png", Texture.class, param);
manager.load("game/poison.png", Texture.class, param);
manager.load("game/regen.png", Texture.class, param);
```

I just wanted to know, would it be faster to do it the above way (there's about 20-30 lines similar to this), or this way:

```
String ext = ".png";

manager.load("game/player" + ext, Texture.class, param);
manager.load("game/point" + ext, Texture.class, param);
manager.load("game/poison" + ext, Texture.class, param);
manager.load("game/regen" + ext, Texture.class, param);
```

Many thanks in advance to any answers.

Comment: Even though there is, it is negligible. Prefer which ever is readable, when performance gain is negligible.

Comment: won't make a difference, when compared to loading of images. The compiler will probably optimize it away anyways.

Comment: Is this really a bottleneck in your code? If not program for clarity

Comment: Have you missed to load game/block.png in the second part?

It is negligible and does not have big impact. But just for your knowledge, first code will create 5 strings and second code with the missing image create 6 strings.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was just curious. How negligible is it though? If say, we're running on a 600MHz Android phone? Would the user notice a difference then?

Comment: "how negligible"? best way to get answer for this would be, profile and see. Gain numbers change based Virtual Machine. But my gut feeling is, you would be spending your time on something from which you can't get any considerable value.

Comment: We are talking fractions of microseconds here, @EVH.

Comment: Loading the images is so much more expensive that how you build you strings doesn't matter.  Instead of loading 30 images, can you have one image which contains all the pictures together?

Answer (score 4):

If you make the `ext` variable `final` then which way you code it doesn't matter as the compiler will concatenate the constants and place them in the constant pool (it will also remove `ext` completely if it isn't referenced otherwise). Write the code which ever way is easier for you to read and maintain. Let the compiler and JIT deal with micro optimizations.

**Example:**

These two snippets of code generate the same bytecode when compiled.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    final String ext = ".png";

    load("asset1" + ext);
    load("asset2" + ext);
    load("asset3" + ext);
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args){


    load("asset1.png");
    load("asset2.png");
    load("asset3.png");
}
```

both generate this bytecode

```
     0: ldc           #2                  // String asset1.png
     2: invokestatic  #3                  // Method load:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     5: ldc           #4                  // String asset2.png
     7: invokestatic  #3                  // Method load:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    10: ldc           #5                  // String asset3.png
    12: invokestatic  #3                  // Method load:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    15: return
```

Comment: that's right, adding final will make string alloc go away. Good point.

Comment: @R.Moeller It is possible that even without `final` that JIT would optimize it at runtime seeing that the value is never modified and local in scope. `javac` optimizations are easier to look at objectively though as you can just look at the emitted bytecode.

Comment: Agree, but i would not rely too much on the compiler being clever if there is the option to explicitely 'final' the field. Compilers as well as code change over time ..

Answer (score -1):

Version 2 would be faster, however you will hardly able to measure it as loading a texture is order of a magnitude more expensive.

Comment: How negligible is it though? If say, we're running on a 600MHz Android phone? Would the user notice a difference then?

Comment: I'd say completely negligible probably loading a texture probably is like 100 times or more expensive.

Comment: -1 for telling nonsense. There is no way you can say one or the other will be faster. The utmost one could say is: With compiler X, on JVM Y and hardware Z, Version A is probably a fraction of a microsecond faster/slower than Version B.

Comment: You are telling nonsense Mr.  ' "asset1"+ext ' will allocate a new String object, which will be slower than NOT allocating anything like in "asset1.png". This holds true in any VM, as "doing something" is always slower than "doing nothing". You have now clue, sorry. Declaring ext final as Dev proposed actually solves this.

Comment: Actually, it seems likely that both versions would compile to the same byte code.

Comment: @Hollis Depends on wether the compiler will (and is allowed) to optimize it. Add some more indirections or declare it as non-final instance field (or non-final in another class) and it won't.